# validate :terms boolean in rails_admin user update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

I set up the validation of the terms checkbox in my user model
(N.B.: only in the model, **not in the database**)

```
validates :terms, acceptance: true, allow_nil: false
```

so that when you register you have to check the corresponding checkbox.

In my `users_controller.rb`, the `update` function contains:

```
@user.terms = true
```

In **rails_admin** though, the update function is still not working (it says `Terms must be accepted`). How can I set the `:terms` field to be automatically true in rails_admin before saving?

Comment: it seems to me that instead of setting `terms` to `true` to fool your validation on update, you should be setting the validation on terms to only run on `create`.   Unless there is a non admin update action that still does require terms

Comment: @MichaelGorman if I write the create function like this `def create
    @user.terms = true
  end` and remove that line from update, then the profile update won't work

Comment: it would be updating the validations line to be `validates :terms, acceptance: true, allow_nil: false, on: :create`. this will require the terms to on the create action but not validate it on update actions.  if this goes against your use case though, you could also add a hidden field on the admin form to submit the `terms = true`

Comment: @MichaelGorman your `on: :create` suggestion worked :) if you add it as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only want the user to have to accept terms on the create action.  It is best to set the validation to only check on the create action.

```
 validates :terms, acceptance: true, allow_nil: false, on: :create
```